# R Convert a datatable into percentage table columnwise

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, percentage

I am trying to convert this table into percentage table columnwise.

| Class | Jan2021 | Feb 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 50 | 100 |
| B | 50 | 150 |
| C | 100 | 100 |

I am expecting this table.

| Class | Jan2021 | Feb 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 25% | 28.57% |
| B | 25% | 42.86% |
| C | 50% | 28.57% |

```
x <- data.frame(class = c("A", "B", "C"),
                Jan2021 = c(50,50,100),
                Feb2021 = c(100,150,100))
```

I could do this, but I have lots of columns/rows with different names. Is there an easier way to calculate the percentage for each column?

```
x_pct = mutate(x, 
            Jan_pct = Jan2021 / sum(Jan2021) *100,
            Feb_pct = Feb2021 / sum(Feb2021) *100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::mutate_if()` and `scales::percent`:

```
x %>% 
  mutate_if(endsWith(names(.),"2021"),function(x) x / sum(x)) %>% 
  mutate_if(endsWith(names(.),"2021"),scales::percent, accuracy = 0.01)
```

Output:

```
  class Jan2021 Feb2021
1     A  25.00%  28.57%
2     B  25.00%  42.86%
3     C  50.00%  28.57%
```

Comment: A note that `mutate_if()` is deprecated for `across()`: `x %>% mutate(across(ends_with("2021"), function(x) x / sum(x)) %>% ...`

Comment: Didn’t know. Thanks for telling

Answer (score 3):

You can use `across` -

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%  mutate(across(-class, ~paste(round(prop.table(.) * 100, 2), '%')))

#  class Jan2021 Feb2021
#1     A    25 % 28.57 %
#2     B    25 % 42.86 %
#3     C    50 % 28.57 %
```

Or `lapply` in base R -

```
x[-1] <- lapply(x[-1], function(x) paste(round(prop.table(x) * 100, 2), '%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(janitor)
x %>%
  adorn_percentages("col") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2)


 class Jan2021 Feb2021
     A  25.00%  28.57%
     B  25.00%  42.86%
     C  50.00%  28.57%
```